# Is it possible to save, name, and delete big query queries through either the Java And PI or command line functions?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries
only describes web UI access or these functions?
Is there any way to perform them programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know  - not as of now!
See details in [Permalink to queries](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=304) request
Take a look at #5 and #7

#5 - This feature finally escaped into the wild. Enjoy! (and as always, feedback is welcome)

#7 - [Usual disclaimer -- this is subject to change and I can't promise anything.]

... current plan is to:

- Release it as a UI-only feature to get some initial feedback and make
  any adjustments that are needed.
- Add support for bq.py, so that it
  can be easily scripted up for batch jobs.
- Enable our API endpoint
  for external usage.